# Apertium translator. Is there a way to get the original phrase

Tags: nlp, translation, translate, apertium

Is there a way in apertium translator to get the original phrase for a translation?

I.E. get something like:

```
phrase: {
  original: { Hola, buenos días},
  translated: {Hello, good morning}
}
```

I need that in order to make a mechanism to improve the translations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're sending a corpus through the command-line interface, e.g.

```
xzcat corpus.sme.xz | sed 's/$/ ./' | apertium -f html-noent sme-nob > translated.nob.mt
```

then you can try simply

```
xzcat corpus.sme.xz | paste - translated.nob.mt
```

afterwards to get the input next to the output. That's assuming you want to split things on newlines. The `sed` is there to ensure words aren't moved across newlines (rules tend not to move across sentence boundaries).

This will be fast, but it's a bit hacky and there are many edge cases.

---

If you want more control, one way would be to install the [JSON API](http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/APy) locally and send one request at a time.

If you've got a recent Debian/Ubuntu (or are using one of the [apertium repos](http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Prerequisites_for_Debian)), you can get the API with

```
sudo apt install apertium-apy
sudo systemctl start apertium-apy   # start it right now
sudo systemctl enable apertium-apy  # let it start on next boot
```

And then you can translate like this:

```
$ echo 'Jeg liker ikke ansjos' | curl --data-urlencode 'q@-' 'localhost:2737/translate?langpair=nob|nno'
{"responseDetails": null, "responseData": {"translatedText": "Eg likar ikkje ansjos"}, "responseStatus": 200}
```

(or from Javascript with standard ajax requests, some docs at http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Apertium-apy/Debian and http://wiki.apertium.org/wiki/Apertium-apy#Usage )

Note that apertium-apy by default serves the pairs that are in /usr/share/apertium/modes; if you start it manually (instead of through systemctl) you can point it at a different path.

---

If you want to produce the JSON format you had in your example, the easiest way would be to use `jq` (`sudo apt install jq`), e.g.

```
$ orig="Jeg liker ikke ansjos"
$ echo "$orig" \
  | curl -Ss --data-urlencode 'q@-' 'localhost:2737/translate?langpair=nob|nno' \
  | jq "{phrase: {original:\"$orig\", translated:.responseData.translatedText }}"
{
  "phrase": {
    "original": "Jeg liker ikke ansjos",
    "translated": "Eg likar ikkje ansjos"
  }
}
```

or on a corpus:

```
xzcat corpus.nob.xz | while read -r orig; do 
  echo "$orig" \
    | curl -Ss --data-urlencode 'q@-' 'localhost:2737/translate?langpair=nob|nno' \
    | jq "{phrase: {original:\"$orig\", translated:.responseData.translatedText}}";
done
```

(A simple test of 500 lines showed this taking 23.7s wall clock time while the `paste` version took 5.5s.)